# Fedora 14 - Error 5 - No space on Disk - After installation

Tags: linux, fedora

I am new to Fedora, am still figure my way through it. I was going about tweaking it and preparing it to my needs, While installing through yum I dont have much other than the fact that I have to search for the packages. But when I open "Add/remove software" of Fedora. I am greeted with " No space left on the disk" and when I seek for more details it says " Disk Error :[errno 5] Input/output error"

I did some research and I saw that it usually occurs during installation, but here I have successfully installed it.

Can someone help me with it? Later on I even had notification of the same warning. And mind you I got loads of free space.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possibly a permissions problem?  You could temporarily disable SELinux, and retry: `su; setenforce 0` in the terminal to disable SELinux.

Comment: I should add this.  This is important: If disabling SELinux fixed the problem, don't just leave it disabled. Install setroubleshootd and re-enable SELinux, and learn what needs to be done to fix permissions.

Comment: Thanks @JeffG, after restart havnt had any problem as yet. Will try your suggestion the next time I encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Fedora but it may be worth looking at how the disk is partitioned.  Run  the command df -h (from a command line) and take a look if one particular partitions use is at 100%.  If so you will need to repartition or modify the size of that parition

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of my discs are that full. Check this out.

`$ df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3              50G  8.6G   39G  19% /

tmpfs                 3.8G  412K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm

/dev/sr0              3.3G  3.3G     0 100% /media/Fedora 14 x86_DVD
/dev/sda5             251G   40G  211G  16% /media/C8B0916`